# How to have a featured blog item in Cloudscribe

Tags: cloudscribe

I'm  creating a blog using Cloudscribe, and I want to be able to select one post as being a featured post. 
I expect the best way to achieve this is to store the 'featured' posts blog ID in the settings for the blog and check this value any time I load posts into memory

Question is - where is the right place to store the featured post BlogID? (assuming my guesswork above is correct enough)

I'm happy to figure everything out from there, but I'm pretty new to MVC so I'm slow at best, an expert pointer would give me better confidence

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are looking for a way to show that on your home page? There isn't a built in feature specifically for "featured posts" in cloudscribe.SimpleContent. There is a built in ViewComponent for showing "recent posts". Assuming you are using SimpleContent pages for the home page that can be enabled by a checkbox under Administration > Content Settings.

If you are using something else for the home page then you can invoke the ViewComponent from either your layout or index view like this:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("RecentPosts", new { viewName = "RecentPosts", numberToShow = 3 })
```

If "recent posts" isn't close enough for your goal of "featured posts" then you could make your own custom viewcomponent possibly by copying/modifying the [RecentPostsViewComponent.cs](https://github.com/joeaudette/cloudscribe.SimpleContent/blob/master/src/cloudscribe.SimpleContent.Web/ViewComponents/RecentPostsViewComponent.cs)

and using a config class to keep settings for the id or ids of featured posts since there is nothing currently built in to mark a post as featured.

Comment: Yes I just want to boxout one article on my Posts List Page. I create FeaturedPostViewComponent.cs locally (under directory 'ViewComponents'), should I also make a ViewModel too

Comment: Please ignore last comment, pressed enter at the wrong time!

Comment: Can I create FeaturedPostViewComponent.cs locally, under the directory 'ViewComponents'? Also, if I need to change the ViewModel (say to fetch just the featured post), could I create a ViewModel locally too? Forgive my inexperience, my questions will become less vague over time I hope!

Comment: yes you can make a local viewcomponent, you can use the same viewmodel if it has what you need or make a new one if not. Then put your view under /Shared/Components/FeaturedPost

Comment: I will consider adding a IsFeatured property on posts in the future and baking a in a viewcomponent for it, but it should be pretty straightforward to implement it locally for now

Comment: if you only want a single post the post itself could be used as the view model

Comment: As ever, very grateful for your time Joe. I've implemented it to boxout the most recent post for now, something I was able to achieve with a simple Partial View. But I have it on my list to do it the way you suggested, my own introduction to ViewComponents and the rolling of my own ViewModel to boot